# Can you style a div with a checkbox when the checkbox is within an adjacent div using only css?

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I have been struggling with this and I have no idea how to get it to work.  I'm finding CSS VERY frustrating but it may be because I'm a noob.  Anyway, I am trying to use a checkbox to hide a DIV but I want the checkbox within an adjacent div so I can style it with a label.

The end result should be headings with years (ie. 2014, 2013, 2012. etc) with a checkbox. When you click the checkbox all of the months are displayed with corresponding checkboxes. When you click the checkbox for the month, the days are displayed.

I can make it work if the  are directly above the  but then it's extremely difficult to format the input and label into a header that looks good.

```
    <style type="text/css">

html
    {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }

p
    {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }

#container
    {
        width:900px;
        height:auto;
        background-color: #DDD;
        margin:0 auto;
    }

.header
    {
        width: 100%;
        height: 25px;
        outline: 1px solid #000;
        outline-offset: -1px;
    }

#year
    {
        width:800px;
        height: auto;
        background-color: #666;
        margin:0px auto;
    }

#month
    {
        width:750px;
        height: auto;
        background-color: #FFF;
        margin-left:50px;
    }

#day
    {
        width:700px;
        height: auto;
        background-color: #09F;
        margin-left:50px;
    }

#dayinfo
    {
        width:675px;
        height: auto;
        background-color:#0CF;
        margin-left:25px;
    }

.upper
{
    height:50px;
    width:800px;
    background-color:#F00;
}

.sub
{
    height:50px;
    width:800px;
    background-color:#0F3;
}

.clear
    {
        clear:both;
    }

input ~ .sub
    {
        display:none;
    }

input:checked ~ .sub
    {
        display: inline;
    }





    </style>


<div id="container">
<div id="containerheader" class="header"><p>Calandar</p></div>

    <div id="year" class="main">
    <!-- <div id="yearheader" class="header"></div> -->
    <input type="checkbox" id="yearbox"><label for="yearbox">Year</label>
            <div id="month" class="sub">
                <div id="monthheader" class="header"></div>
                <div id="day" class="sub">
                    <div id="dayheader" class="header"></div>
                    <div id="dayinfo">
                        <p>day info goes here</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>


</div>
```

This code works but you can't easily style the .  It would be awesome if it would work with the  inside of a .

Thanks.

Comment: i'm sorry that i found the question unclear :(. could you make a diagram on what you want to achieve?

Comment: Are you saying you want Year to show, Month to be hidden, but Day to show, and once you check the checkbox, Month will show? I agree, desired outcome is unclear.

Comment: You can't do this just with CSS unfortunately.  The minute you nest the checkbox inside the header, you can't target the `.sub` because CSS can't traverse back up the tree.

Comment: I think the OP wants this functionality: http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/SWq56/1/ but with the ability to style a parent container.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion.  The end result should be headings with years (ie. 2014, 2013, 2012. etc) with a checkbox.  When you click the checkbox all of the months are displayed with corresponding checkboxes.  When you click the checkbox for the month, the days are displayed.

Does that make more sense?  Thanks for the comments.

Comment: I fixed up the post so hopefully that is more clear.  I was pretty agitated when I first posted it.  The code posted does work but the formatting doesn't look very good.  I wanted to work on the functionality before hammering out the details. It's based on this:

http://bradclicks.com/CSSplay/foldingList.html

...code but I couldn't get any formatting to work with the ul or li elements so that the stupid thing would display in a block format (rectangles, one above the other ).